# Assigning a list of numbers to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have list of numbers in a file `test.txt`:

```
31
32
26
28
27
30
24
15
4
2
1
3
```

I want to assign this list to a variable in a script which can be used as loop variable for a FOR loop. The variable should be assigned like this:
`LIST="31 32 26 28 27 30 24 15 4 2 1 3"` (space separated).
This list should be assigned by the script dynamically.  How can I do this?

Comment: Do you really want to assign to a variable? You can construct a for loop with the values from the file (see answer of @Cyrus).

Answer (score 4):

In Bash, you can use:

```
list=$(<test.txt)
```

This uses the notation for [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) but avoids the overhead of executing an external program.  The non-Bash alternative is:

```
list=$(cat test.txt)
```

This also works in Bash, of course, but incurs the overhead of the separate `cat` process.

You can use back-quotes `` list=`cat test.txt` `` but you should generally use the `$(…)` notation instead.  It is much easier to deal with quoting and nesting using the `$(…)` notation than it is using back-quotes.

Comment: In pretty much any context where you're going to use the string of numbers, you don't need to worry about the difference.  If you decide it does matter, then `list=$(echo $(<test.txt))` can do the job.

Comment: Well, OP insists on a space separated string specifically, that's the main reason for going into such lengths.. I would prefer an array instead...that gives much more controll :D

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line";
done < test.txt
```

or

```
for line in $(cat test.txt); do
  echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Upvote, with a  strong preference  for the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
LIST=`tr  '\n' ' '   < test.txt` 
echo $LIST
```

Comment: It works, but it is neither conventional nor necessary to use `tr` where `cat` would do, amongst others.  Indeed, with Bash, you can even use ``LIST=`<test.txt` `` to get the desired result.  It's also better to use `$(…)` than back-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var=`cat test.txt`
```

... that's all you need. You can then iterate over `$var` in a for loop.

If you specifically need a space-separated string, `echo $var` will give you that.

Comment: Note that `$(…)` is better than using back-quotes directly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In this particular case, no, it isn't one bit better--but I like your answer better anyway, since it uses builtins only.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST="$(tr -s '\n' ' ' <<< "$(<file)")"
#LIST="$(tr -s '\n' ' ' <<< "$(cat file)")"
#LIST="$(cat file |tr -s '\n' ' ')"
#LIST="$(echo "$(<file)" |tr -s '\n' ' ')"
#LIST="$(tr -s '\n' ' ' <file)"
LIST="${LIST/% /}" #trims the space at end
printf "%s" "$LIST"
```

The command `tr -s '\n' ' '` replaces newline with a single space. A space is also added at end in `$LIST` which is omitted by `LIST=${LIST/% /}`

Another way:

```
LIST="$(echo $(<file))" # $(<file) must not be quoted here
printf "%s" $LIST  # Use quote as normal, $LIST without quote will lose spaces
```

Note: Use variables quoted (double quote), otherwise you may lose white spaces.

Comment: This all seems inordinately complex for a very simple exercise.